# Reporting Services text box not staying in place

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to absolutely position 2 text boxes but the 2nd box is being pushed down as shown below...I've tried various combinations of Send to Front/Send to Back but nothing appears to influence their positions ?? Any ideas ?

Preview mode

[image: Preview mode]

Design mode

[image: Design mode]

Updated with actual PDF view of page....

[image: Actual PDF]

Comment: Try stick them into a rectangle.

Comment: Nope, cut both the textboxes and pasted them into a rectangle but still same result

Comment: The problem is actually the Preview mode !, when I actually save to PDF it all lines up as expected. Will post pdf image

Comment: Your textboxes overlap. Not all renderers support overlapping. Either shrink the Maintenance textbox so it only just fits the text of better still might be to use a single textbox and use two placeholders. To add a placeholder, right-click inside the textbox and choose add place holder, you can still adjust fonts sizes etc interdependently even thought they are in the same control.